# retrieval of data in 2 periods possible with one (mysql) query possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure, pls see below.

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  
,data_i int NOT NULL 
,data_t text NOT NULL 
,date date NOT NULL
);
```

Is it possible to extract data_i with a certain period and extract data_t within a different period by means of a single query? I believe not, but i'd like to check this via this site. (Reason for such query is saving server capacity and bandwidth as data_i contains just a figure and data_t may contain much more data)

Comment: With "data_t contains much more data", you mean more distinct values, or the size of the text field?

Comment: the size of the textfield

Comment: SELECT * FROM my-table WHERE a=x OR b=y;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can union queries like

```
SELECT 1 as type, id, data_i, '' as content FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN ... AND ...
UNION
SELECT 2, id, 0, data_t FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN ... AND ...
```